# Tutorial about objective-c garbage collection

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I would like to understand garbage collection in objective-c.

I know how to work with memory in C-like languages and in languages where I don't care about memory. But I don't understand when to use autorelease, retain, dealloc and everything else, so I get errors and memory leaks.

Could someone propose me a good tutorial to understand this all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely start at the definitive source: Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

There's probably good discussion of this issue in most of the better Cocoa programming books, and elsewhere on this site, but that's where even those places will ultimately direct you.